# Need to vectorize solution that using nested loops (transform data frame from long to wide format)

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I have following data frame and need to do transformation from long into wide format:

```
symbol side price
1      A    B     1
2      A    S     2
3      B    B     3
4      C    B     4
5      B    S     5
```

**Explanation:** for every symbol must exists two lines with side B and side S. Need to find these lines and transform them into wide format:

`[symbol, first-comed side (B or S), price of side B, price of side S]`

If one line exists but another is missing, then put NA value to appropriate price value. For example if line with side B exists, but with side S is missing, then put NA to price of side S.

Output results must be following:

```
  symbol side price_B price_S
1      A    B      1      2
2      B    B      3      5
3      C    B      4     NA
```

For symbols A and B we have lines with sides A and B so we transform them without NA's. Side B was first in order then we put only B side to "side" column. For symbol C we have only side B but not side S so we put NA value to the "price_S" column.

How to vectorize it?

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear what was being asked.  Oh well.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reshape` gets the prices:

```
prices <- reshape(x, direction='wide', idvar='symbol', timevar='side', v.names='price', sep='')
prices
##   symbol priceB priceS
## 1      A      1      2
## 3      B      3      5
## 4      C      4     NA
```

`aggregate` gets the first price:

```
first <- aggregate(side ~ symbol, data=x, FUN=head, n=1)
first
##   symbol side
## 1      A    B
## 2      B    B
## 3      C    B
```

`merge` puts them together:

```
merge(first, prices)
##   symbol side priceB priceS
## 1      A    B      1      2
## 2      B    B      3      5
## 3      C    B      4     NA
```